# Where is PackageReference entry in .csproj file in ASP.NET Core 3?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, csproj

Previously in ASP.NET Core 2.0 when you create a new web project with `dotnet new web` and you open `.csproj` file you would have `PackageReference` entry like this:

[image]

But today I started playing with ASP.NET Core 3.1, and I noticed that when you create a new project in the same manner, the .csproj file contains only this:

[image]

Where did the `PackageReference` entry go and how does ASP.NET Core knows how to build and run the project without this information?

Comment: See [the migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference). Specifically: _Projects that target the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web SDK implicitly reference the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App framework._.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution mechanism of shared framework reference assemblies and build logic changed. It is no longer based on NuGet and uses `FrameworkReference` items.

The Web SDK (`Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`) references this framework automatically.

If you need to use types / APIs only available in ASP.NET Core and not via separate NuGet packages from non-Web projects (`Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"`), you can use:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```